# Creating new key => value pairs out of existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an arrays that looks like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [food] => Pizza
            [music] => Rock
            [color] => blue
            [name] => John
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [food] => Toast
            [music] => Jazz
            [color] => yellow
            [name] => Greg
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [food] => Steak
            [music] => Classical
            [color] => green
            [name] => Steve
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [food] => Cake
            [music] => Blues
            [color] => red
            [name] => Peter
        )

)
```

How do I create a new array where I combine some of the content to new `key => value` pairs, like `Peter => Cake`?

I already managed to use some values, but they are not connected to the keys:

```
$myArr = *The array posted above*
$newArray = array();

foreach ( $myArr as $arr ) {
    array_push( $newArray, $arr->food );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be something like:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ( $myArr as $arr ) {
    $newArray[$arr->name] = $arr->food;
}
```

Note that duplicate names get overwritten with the last occurrence.